# Nth-child and grandparent or second level of child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent, css-selectors

This is probably very simple but can't figured it out!

I have this kind of code:

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child" id="1"></div>
        <div class="child" id="2"></div>
        <div class="child" id="3"></div>
        <div class="child" id="4"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child" id="5"></div>
        <div class="child" id="6"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I tryed:

```
$('.grandparent .child:nth-child(3n)').css("margin-right","0px");
```

So I need the **child #3** and **child #6** to have margin-right:0px.

But it's always refering to **.parent** as the 3n child, not the selected class **.grandparent** so only the **child #3** is affected.

Any idea of a simple way to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.grandparent .child').filter(function(i){
    return (i+1)%3 === 0;
}).css('margin-right', '0px');
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YqA2D/) (using `color` to make it easier to see).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Thank you David, I was sticking with nth-child!